# Using javascript: How do I add to text when clicking the submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fairly new to javascript and I'm having great trouble making a 'To Do' list in an app I'm developing. At the moment you can type in the text field and click submit which will bring up what you typed along with a checkbox next to it.
That's all fine and good, but if I add anything else to do it the previous text and checkbox is overwritten and I can't figure out how add to the list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Html:

```
Enter What To Do <input id='userInput' size=60>
<button onClick='userSubmit()'>Submit</button>
<BR><P>
<div id='result'></div>
```

JS:

```
function userSubmit() {
    var UI=document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML='<input type="checkbox">' + UI;
}
```

Comment: Are you averse to using Jquery?

Comment: Not at all!
I'm just not sure how to go about it

Comment: There is no error as such, it works fine!
I just want to know how to add to what I put, for example.
If I type 1, then submit, then 2, then submit.
I want it to display like 1, then 2 underneath it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML+='<input type="checkbox"> '+UI+'<br>';
```

Comment: @Praveen; for first time it wont't but later it will append the new entry

Comment: @Praveen u missed the "+" operator in ur fiddle code :)

Comment: My bad, only through this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479497/using-javascript-how-do-i-add-to-text-when-clicking-the-submit-button#comment32419449_21479497) I understood OP's question fully.  +1 I will revert my comments.

Comment: That works great thanks so much! 
Now, is there a way to it to display vertically? and Also have a delete icon? or is that calling upon much more JS ?

Comment: look at the end of line; der is a "<br>" tag dat will display vertically

Comment: Yes thank you ! :)

Would a delete button be hard to implement? just a small X next to each entry?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function userSubmit() {
      var UI=document.getElementById('userInput').value;
      document.getElementById('result').appendChild('<p><input type="checkbox"> '+UI+'</input></p>);
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: That isn't working for me, nothing comes up when I click submit

Comment: @user1708762: you forgot to close the bracket

Comment: @user3236263 sorry man! i forgot to close one bracket. Try it now.